# Inverter's Chain Sizing

Tags: digital-logic, asic

if i have a chain of 4 identical inverters connected in series and i want to size them to obtain a specific propagation delay time, how do I approach this problem ?
i know that there are several textbooks and papers that talk about sizing for a minimum delay but that is not the case here.

Comment: Explain how you "size" an inverter?

Comment: i mean choosing approriate transistor width and length given a supply voltage, device thresholds.

Comment: Since that won't work, you might want to explain what you're *really* trying to do.

Comment: im working on a circuit that delays a clock signal by some amount. the circuit contain several stages of delay elements consisting of 4 series inverters.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to design a combinational logic circuit for an exact, specific value of delay is not going to work.

The delay will vary with temperature (and the chips heat up as they run), with manufacturing variation, and with supply voltage. The only reasonable thing to do is to design for either a maximum delay or a minimum delay, but not both and not a specific delay.

If this is a purely academic exercise, then I suggest a Monte Carlo simulation.